# Add page to PDF using Node WKHTMLTOPDF

Tags: node.js, wkhtmltopdf

I have a HTML template created using Handlebar.
Let us say I want to create 10 HTML file from that.
Now I want to print the 10 pages to the single pdf.
How can I do so in wkhtmltopdf?
How can I add pages in wkhtmltopdf?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I recommender either jspdf or puppeteer, not wkhtmltopdf. But jspdf is not strictly generated from html.

Comment: I need to do it in server side only. Somewhere I read the JSPDF is not good with node and puppeteer will be slow for my use case. I have to generate 100 pdf in almost 30 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add multiple pages to the pdf we have to take help of css page break.